# How to pass state from function to class - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `hooks`.
I have a function to use `dropzone` library:

```
    export function UploadFile() {
        const [files] = useState([]);
        return (
          <MaterialDropZone
            files={files}
            showPreviews
            maxSize={5000000}
            filesLimit={5}
            text="to upload"
          />
        );
      }

class MyClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };

    }

...
render(){

return (
<UploadFile />)


}
```

now I want to access `files`  inside `MyClass` component to uplaod my files. but I don't know how to access `files`.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot access the state defined in child component in your parent component directly.
What you can do is that you can define `files` state in your parent component `MyClass` and pass it as props in your child component `UploadFile`.